# Is there any way to send text msg through an email?

Tags: email

Is there any way to send text msg through an email in bulk? Please guide..

Comment: What do you mean? Sending an email from a phone to a list of people off your mail server?

Comment: Choose Plain Text as the message format in your email client and send away.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, but you will need to know the phone number AND carrier. This [link](http://www.emrupdate.com/blogs/ducknet/archive/2008/11/30/how-to-send-email-text-messages-to-any-cell-phone-for-free-from-your-computer.aspx) gives you the email address format to send an email to arrive as a text on most major carriers. I just tested the @txt.att.net, and it works as expected.

Figuring out how to do it in bulk will be your own to figure out, but should be no different than sending any other mass mail.

Edit: I should note, that you can reply via text and will arrive in your senders inbox.

Answer (score 0):

There are commercial services that can be used to convert e-mail messages to SMS.

Because SMS has a cost attached to it (from the network operators), you're unlikely to find a free way to do this (in large volume at least) unless supported by advertising.

Comment: [It seems like you haven't got the memo](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5280/embrace-the-non-googlers).

Comment: Maybe you should text it to him.

Comment: Oops - sorry team!